# Is the repetitive use of foreign keys invalid here?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating an inventory system that uses a series of zones and sectors alongside bin locations. Each zone is an area of the building. Each sector is just simply a subdivision of that zone. The final locations would be labeled as bins. In my diagram, the "Bins" table has the 'warehouse_id' as a foreign key. This 'warehouse_id' is also located in the Sectors and Zones tables. Do I need these foreign keys to repeat like this? I am under the understanding that I can obtain the 'warehouse_id' from the Bin location through the other relationships.

I want to remove the duplicate 'warehouse_id' from my Sectors table to avoid duplicate data. Is this worth the data space? Or is it going to make queries much more difficult? If my Bins table only has the 'sector_id' I could reach into the sectors table, then zones, then warehouses to find what the warehouse is?

It's been a few years and I'm brushing up on SQL. Making this inventory system and then diving into queries. I have a pretty good understanding of general programming and computer science but databases are not my forte.

[image: SQL Diagram]

I have updated some tables, addresses are cut off at the top but it was the inventory redundancies I was worried about.

[image: Updated inventory]

Comment: Ah... redundancy. It's so useful, and so dangerous...

Comment: If those redundant `warehouse_id`s become inconsistent (they will, believe me) which one will you consider the ultimate source of truth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are storing foreign keys in the `Sectors` and `Bins` tables redundantly, which risks creating data anomalies.

For example:

Bins:

| bin_id | sector_id | zone_id | warehouse_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 4567 | 789 | 6 |

Sectors:

| sector_id | zone_id | warehouse_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4567 | 890 | 17 |

Zones:

| zone_id | warehouse_id |
| --- | --- |
| 789 | 45 |
| 890 | 121 |

Clearly some of these values have mistakes, but which ones? Are the values in `Bins` correct, and the other tables have mistakes, or vice versa? How do you make sense of this?

The way to eliminate possible data anomalies is to avoid redundant storage of attributes. In `Bins`, store only the `sector_id` foreign key, and get rid of the `zone_id` and `warehouse_id`. In `Sectors`, get rid of `warehouse_id`.

If you do this, you end up with what is called a *normalized database design*, and it's a great way to make it mistake-proof.

This requires you to write queries with joins if you need a query result to relate the bin to its respective zone or warehouse.

This shouldn't be considered *hard.* This is the normal way to use SQL.

Comment: Thank you, I was worried about these becoming massive redundancies. I have updated my tables since.